# NoSuchDriverError: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-java

I am using Appium to automate my App, when I run my code, my app crashes randomly by losing driver, and I have to run my code again, this occurs often, can anyone help me out.

Here is the error, I've copied from Appium server logs:

```
Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchDriverError: A session is either terminated or not started
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:315:15)
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\@appium\base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:518:15
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at next (C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
[AppiumDriver@2515]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Imran Ullah\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```